# Maven deploy failed?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, archiva

**Hi,
I created new maven artifact using archiva, in order to share updated jar projects with my team. when I try to deploy the project I got this fail:**

```
downloading: http://**VirtualMachineName:8888/groupId**/webInfra/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata **groupId**:webInfra:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to stmaven (http://**VirtualMachineName:8888**): Failed to transfer http://**VirtualMachineName:8888/groupId**/webInfra/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 504, Proxy Timeout ( The connection timed out.  )
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-08T10:04:00+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/249M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project webInfra: Failed to retrieve remote metadata il.co.stms-automation:webInfra:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata **groupId**:webInfra:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to stmaven (http://VirtualMachineName:8888): Failed to transfer http://**VirtualMachineName:8888/groupId**/webInfra/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Error code 504, Proxy Timeout ( The connection timed out.  ) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

this what I added to pom.xml file:

    <repository>
      <id>stmaven</id>
      <name>stmaven</name>
      <url>http://stmaven:8888</url>
    </repository>


 what added to setting.xml file:
<servers>

    <server>
      <id>VirtualMachineName</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>pass</password>
    </server>
    <!---->


  </servers>


  <mirrors>

    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>archiva</mirrorOf>
      <name>maven archiva Mycompany</name>
      <url>http://VirtualMachineName:8888/#browse/**groupId**</url>
    </mirror>

  </mirrors>
```

**Note : I'm very new with creating and maintain maven repository.**

**Thank you**

Comment: Herer is the problem. ` Error code 504, Proxy Timeout`..

Comment: Proxy declared at settings.xml file, should I declare it on another place?

Comment: It does not matter that you have declared it...the point is it has timeout's...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to declare the below parameter in the POM :

```
<distributionManagement>

    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Releases</name>
        <url>http://localHost:8080/repository/YourRepo/</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://localHost:8080/repository/YourRepo/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

> Both repository (release and snapshots ) point in same repo in archiva
>
> Snapshot option should be enabled on YourRepo in archiva

you have to declare the below parameter in the Setting XML:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <servers>
<server>
  <id>YourRepo</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
<server>
  <id>releases</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>password</password>
</server>
</servers>
</settings>
```

After that you can run : `mvn deploy`

It works for me

Comment: you are beeed :D, big beeed